# Working Directory Spontaneously Deleted

Tags: data-recovery, data-loss

On `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`, I was working in nvim in bash. I had multiple terminal tabs open. There was a `.git` directory in the working directory. At some point, after closing one terminal tab, I noticed that the directory I was working in does not exist any more.

I checked whether I had accidentally moved the directory by running
`sudo find / -name "some-file.txt"` from the home directory, where `some-file.txt` is a filename I am sure to have been in the missing directory.

I double checked bash history, and after the last `git commit` and `git rebase -i HEAD --root` I made, only commands indicating my search for the lost directory are there. I remember in the interactive rebase I renamed the initial commit. If I did something wrong there (as in: `drop` all commits, for instance), this would still not explain the whole directory to be deleted.

I know, this is a very general question. But it is due to the nature of the problem that I cannot provide more details or reproduce the bug.

**What could be the reason for this?** (Whenever I try to `rm -r` a directory with a `.git` repository that has commits, I am asked to confirm the removal of the commits `rm: remove write-protected regular file ...`. This does not happen when I run this command as `sudo`, but I am quite sure I didn't enter my password. On top of the bash history, this makes me think that I did not delete all the directory myself accidentally.)

**What could I do to restore my data?** I hadn't pushed, and I have managed to store the files in the open vim buffers, to answer the most obvious parts myself already.

Comment: It's possible you moved the directory elsewhere accidentally.

Comment: Don't forget if you run a command with `sudo` you won't be asked for a password if you're still within the time limit of the prior *elevated command* at that terminal where a `sudo` command was used... You've not given any OS or release details which would allow a more precise response  (ie. your mentioning not giving a password may not have been required for a `sudo` though there are Ubuntu products where the password is required instantly but you weren't specific)

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for the comment I have added the Ubunutu release now. Are there more details missing which could be helpful?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach ``sudo grep "seome-file.txt" \``? Assuming you meant `/`, that searches for the string `seome-file.txt` in the `/` directory, which would still be an error unless you told `grep` to recurse. And even then it would still check the contents, not the filename. It's meaningless as a confirmation of anything.

Comment: @muru You are right, sorry, first I had some typos and second I was confusing `grep` and `find`. I didn't find the file with `find` either.

Comment: Your find command also doesn't do what you think it does

Answer (score 0):

**FIND THE CAUSE:**

`nvim` also comes with several commands (and pre-installed extensions) that can do this. If you are trying to figure out the cause of the deletion, check your `nvim` logs as well.

**DATA RECOVERY:**

You mentioned a `.git` directory. Did your directory have a git remote? If so, just clone it to local and problem solved.

If not check for a directory named `".trash-{$USER_ID}"` if the original was on a mounted external drive, or `.local/share/Trash` otherwise. It may be in there (unless `rm` was used to delete. In that case, unless you are backing up your file system, it is probably gone.)

**PROTECTING YOUR SYSTEM AGAINST THIS ISSUE:**

This is why you will so often see users on here recommending frequent scheduled backups. I personally use a combination of `Timeshift` and `rsync`.

`Timeshift` can be downloaded via apt. It is primarily for backing up your system files and configuration, and lets you set a recurring backup schedule. You can also run manual backups in cases where you are about to do something risky.

`rsync` comes with Ubuntu. It is just a basic command-line tool for copying files and directories across a network (although it can do so locally as well.)

`Rsync` is not primarily intended as a stand-alone backup program, at least not in the way that `Timeshift` or `Weresync` are. However, it is simple and effective enough at making backups that many of the more comprehensive solutions use it internally for this purpose.

The downside of `rsync` is that there is no *"set it and forget it"* method built in. However, the Ubuntu package managers provide many more backup options, each with its own quirks.

It may be cliche at this point to recommend an aggressive backup strategy, but as you can see, it is cliche for a good reason.

Comment: Regarding remote repo: As I said, I had not pushed. Regarding backups: I am running backups once a week. I lost the work of a day.

Comment: Losing the work of a day still sucks, but it could have been a lot worse. As for the cause, ultimately only you have the resources to figure that out. There are a thousand different ways that data can be deleted. It could have been a rogue bg program running root or a `SIGSEGV`, for all we know. That said, I guarantee that the answer is in a log file somewhere on your system. Btw, did you check your trash-bin yet? As long as it wasn't `rm`ed (as in the system call, not the cli utility), you should be able to find it there